# How to get word combinations from mysql tables grouping words from previous and next rows?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'd like to get more sophisticated version of this approach. My goal is simply to get 1-n word combinations from table, where I have stored single word by row. Word phrases should be constructed according to id order, not just random order.

At the moment I use mysql variables but problem comes, when I try to get combinations bigger than 12 words, because there is a limit on JOIN tables mysql is using internally. Also I have not figured how to get all combinations at once. I get only "word1 word2", "word3 word4" or "word1 word2 word3", "word4 word5 word6" on result, not "word1 word2", "word1 word2 word3", "word1 word2 word3 word4" etc.

```
SELECT  (@word3 := CONCAT(@word3, ' ', w.word)) AS word3,
    (@word2 := CONCAT(@word2, ' ', w.word)) AS word2,
    (@word3 := @word2) _word3,
    (@word2 := w.word) _word2,
    w.book_id

FROM    (SELECT @word3:='') _word3,
    (SELECT @word2:='') _word2,
    word w, text t, chapter c, verse v

WHERE   v.number IN (14) AND c.number IN (21) AND c.book_id IN (1) AND t.verse_id = v.id AND w.id = t.word_id AND v.chapter_id = c.id
```

Chapter, verse and text are used to show the bigger context but basically word table is:

### Words

```
id, 
word, 
numeric_value, 
transliteration, 
translation, 
words_count, 
book_id
```

I think join table limit comes because I also want to concatenate transliteration, words count and other fields.

I also tried this on select:

```
if(@word3, @word3 := CONCAT(@word3, ' ', w.word), @word3 := '') AS word3,

if(@word2, @word2 := CONCAT(@word2, ' ', w.word), @word2 := '') AS word2,
```

But for some reason it didnt work.

So what is the best way to get related word combinations from table, where words are on separate rows?

### EXAMPLE WORD TABLE DATA:

```
this
is
a
phrase
containing
words
on
separate
rows
```

### EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
this is, is a, a phrase, phrase containing, containing words, words on, 
on separate, separate rows, this is a, is a phrase, a phrase containing, 
phrase containing words, containing words on, words on separate, 
on separate rows, ...
```

and so on with 4 to n word combinations.

Comment: Do you want the output tags to be listed in a single field or by column?

Comment: By column, sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: I might be able to provide you with an answer but I need to do some modifications according to your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

With your current schema, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(w.word)
FROM     chapter c
    JOIN verse   v ON v.chapter_id = c.id
    JOIN text    t ON t.verse_id   = v.id
    JOIN word    w ON w.id         = t.word_id
WHERE    c.book_id = 1
     AND c.number  = 21
     AND v.number  = 14
GROUP BY c.book_id, c.number, v.number
```

However, this does seem a bit overly normalised; why not just store the complete text in the `text` table with a [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html) index if appropriate?

Comment: How does this create combinations of 1,2,3,4,...n words? Doesn't it combine all verse words in this case?

I could store whole text on one field, but I still need to get not only word phrases but transliteration, words_count and word values combined as well. Actually word values are the main thing on my project, thats why I normalized data to separate word chunks.

On text table I have:

id
word_id
verse_id

So maybe text.ids could be used to form combinations of the phrases like text.id1 + text.id2, text.id1 + text.id2 + text.id3, ...

Comment: @PHPGAE: Yes, you are correct that this will combine all verse words and not combinations of 1,2,3,4,...n words.  I misunderstood your problem and, indeed, am still finding it hard to imagine what exactly you require (or why).  Perhaps a more concrete example would help?

Comment: I added example data and desired output at the end of the question.

Comment: @PHPGAE: So, for 2-word combinations you only want consecutive words?  You wouldn't, say, want `('phrase', 'rows')` or `('a', 'on')`?  How does one determine the order of words such that consecutive pairs can be identified?

Comment: Yes, consecutive is the right word. Order is on id primary field on text table which has these columns: text.id, text.verse_id and text.word_id references. Ids are in order.

Comment: *Why* do you need such a resultset?  Can it not be better obtained from within your application code?

Comment: I wouldnt need to add more business logic for my app, but current one would handle result set as they are at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This query is based on the following method to parse `CSV` values into multiple rows: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/parsing-csv-values-into-multiple-rows

1. it will extract every words from a string field
2. store every combination from 1 to 4 word(s) in a tag column
3. validate the length (>2) of first and last word of the tags

**THE FOREACH TABLE**

```
pos

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
.
.
.
1000
```

**THE WORDS TABLE**

```
row_id   phrase

1        an example of phrase to tag with many words
2        hello world!
3        another phrase 1000 characters long
```

**THE MYSQL QUERY**

> ```
> SELECT 
> DISTINCT
>  @col1_len:=IF(num=1,@col2_len,@col1_len) AS col1_len
> ,@col1:=IF(num=1,@col2,@col1) AS col1
> ,@col2_len:=IF(num=1,@col3_len,@col2_len) AS col2_len
> ,@col2:=IF(num=1,@col3,@col2) AS col2
> ,@col3_len:=IF(num=1,@col4_len,@col3_len) AS col3_len
> ,@col3:=IF(num=1,@col4,@col3) AS col3
> ,@col4_len:=IF(num=1,LOCATE(' ',content, f.pos ) - f.pos,@col4_len) AS col4_len
> ,@col4:=SUBSTRING(content, f.pos,@col4_len) AS col4
> ,CASE
> WHEN f.num=1
> THEN 
>    @tag:=@col4
> WHEN f.num=2
> THEN
>    @tag:=TRIM(CONCAT(@col3,' ',@col4))
> WHEN f.num=3
> THEN 
>    @tag:=TRIM(CONCAT(@col2,' ',@col3,' ',@col4))
> WHEN f.num=4
> THEN 
>    @tag:=TRIM(CONCAT(@col1,' ',@col2,' ',@col3,' ',@col4))
> END AS tag
> ,CASE
> WHEN f.num=1
> THEN 
>    @valid_tag:=IF(@col4_len > 2,1,0)
> WHEN f.num=2
> THEN
>    @valid_tag:=IF(@col3_len > 2,1,0)
> WHEN f.num=3
> THEN 
>    @valid_tag:=IF(@col2_len > 2,1,0)
> WHEN f.num=4
> THEN 
>    @valid_tag:=IF(@col1_len > 2,1,0)
> END AS valid_tag
> FROM 
> (SELECT 
> CONCAT(' ' ,phrase, ' ') AS content
> ,f1.pos AS pos
> ,f2.pos AS num 
> ,@col1:=''
> ,@col2:=''
> ,@col3:=''
> ,@col4:=''
> ,@col1_len:=0
> ,@col2_len:=0
> ,@col3_len:=0
> ,@col4_len:=0
> FROM words
> LEFT JOIN foreach f1
> ON ( f1.pos < content_len+1 )
> LEFT JOIN foreach f2 
> ON ( f2.pos < 5 )
> WHERE 1=1
> AND row_id IN (1) 
> )f 
> WHERE 1=1
> AND SUBSTRING(content, f.pos - 1, 1)=' '
> HAVING 
> LENGTH(tag)>2
> AND valid_tag=1
> AND col4_len > 2
> ```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
tag

example
example of phrase
phrase
phrase to tag
phrase to tag with
tag
tag with
tag with many
tag with many words
with
with many
with many words
many
many words
words
```